# I want to change the yellow bracket level in VSCode to a more visible colour

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, brackets, text-coloring

I am using VSCode and the (default) Light+ theme, on Windows 10.  I like this theme but have a lot of trouble seeing the yellow against the white - same is true for all the "light" themes, so there is no point changing themes.

I have found `workbench.colorCustomizations` in Settings - specifically changing `editorBracketHighlight.foreground1` , but it won't stay on the colour I have selected (dark blue) - it *sometimes* shows as blue (and not consistently) when I bring up the VSCode editor, but, even if I see blue initially, it switches back to yellow shortly after.  There seem to be various ways to change the settings, but I haven't found one that will stay!

BTW I have specified `editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled` (and this does work, using the old colours), so this is not the problem...

Help would be appreciated! TIA

PS I don't care whether this is associated with my workbench or all projects, and all languages or each language specifically (I am just doing Go right now), as I would want this for all projects, and all languages...

Comment: Thanks, Ryu S., that helps!  I tried to do what you suggested, and here is what I have so far (for one scope): 
    
     "editor.tokenColorCustomizations":{
        "textMateRules": [
          { "scope":                "punctuation.definition.begin.bracket.curly.go",
                "settings": {
                "editorBracketHighlight.foreground1": "#3344F0"
             }
            },

but it doesn't seem to like 'editorBracketHighlight.foreground1' within a scope! TIA

Comment: @Ryu S. Don't know whether you saw the above...  `settings.json` accepts "workbench.colorCustomizations": {    
        "editorBracketHighlight.foreground1": "#3344F0"
    },
but not when `editorBracket...` is in a scope...  TIA

Answer (score 2):

To get a better idea of whats going on behind the scenes, first install the Scope Inspector

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#scope-inspector

then open your `settings.json` with ctrl+shift+P -> "Preferences: Open Settings.json".

Now open a .go file that you want to use as a test subject... and then enable the scope inspector:
`ctrl+shift+p -> Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens & Scopes`

For me I am using a Slice tutorial as example, Light+ on MacOS :[image]

moving around your cursor you will see different scopes are applied to different tokens in your code.

In this example the inspector shows that it has 2 scopes being applied.

To change the color, go to the Settings.json file...

Inside, alongside whatever else you may have added, put in the "editor.tokenColorCustomizations" object with a sub "textMateRules" object, and include the scopes you want to target using the ScopeInspector mentioned above:

```
{
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations":{
    // "comments": "#33FFCC",  //will affect all comments in VSCode...
    "textMateRules": [
      { "scope": "punctuation.definition.bracket.square.go",
         "settings": {
            "foreground": "#8110239f",
            "fontStyle": "bold",
         }
      },
     //.... Other rules you may add for different scopes you find with inspector etc... 
    ]
  } //end "editor.tokenColorCustomizations"
}
```

In this example, The result immediately changes to a dark red:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I can now colour the brackets as desired without using testMateRules, as follows:

```
 "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
"editor.guides.bracketPairs": "active",
"bracket-pair-colorizer-2.forceUniqueOpeningColor": false,
"bracket-pair-colorizer-2.showVerticalScopeLine": true,
"bracket-pair-colorizer-2.showHorizontalScopeLine": true,
"bracket-pair-colorizer-2.colors": [
  "#3344F0",
  "Orchid",
  "LightSkyBlue",
  "Green"
],
```

This seems to work - maybe someone could let me know if there is a problem with this!  Thanks

Comment: looks good, so it seems https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer-2 has been merged into the core vscode stuff, so if you are using color schemes you will just have to remember that this module may override colorings, i see now thats why my light+ didnt have yellow colored brackets (wasnt using this plugin)